# Citation not showing

Tags: reference, latex, biblatex

I have a problem, my citation are not showing but latex file is running probably.

I have created a bib file called thesis with jabref, I used texmaker and the pdf file is produced without an error, but the citation are not appearing, only keys are appearing in boldface.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=numeric, natbib=true,sorting=anyt]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[titletoc,toc]{appendix}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{longtable}            
\usepackage{rotating}
%\bibliography{thesis} % or
\addbibresource{thesis.bib}
\usepackage{array}
\newenvironment{conditions}
  {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} l}}
  {\end{tabular}\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}
\makeatletter
\def\blx@maxline{77}
\makeatother

\newrobustcmd*{\parentexttrack}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@blxinit
  \blx@setsfcodes
  \blx@bibopenparen#1\blx@bibcloseparen
  \endgroup}

\AtEveryCite{%
  \let\parentext=\parentexttrack%
  \let\bibopenparen=\bibopenbracket%
  \let\bibcloseparen=\bibclosebracket}

\makeatother
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\hypersetup{
 colorlinks=true,
 citecolor=Blue,
 linkcolor=Blue,
 urlcolor=Red
}
\hypersetup{ 
citebordercolor=.1 1 .1, 
linkbordercolor=1 0 0, 
 urlbordercolor=1 0 0, }
\renewcommand\nameyeardelim{, }
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}  % set the margins to 1in on all sides
\usepackage{graphicx}              % to include figures
%\usepackage[dvipdfm]{graphicx} \usepackage{bmpsize}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}               % great math stuff
\usepackage{amsfonts}              % for blackboard bold, etc
\usepackage{amsthm}                % better theorem \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{mcode}
%\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
% various theorems, numbered by section
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
% numbers
\newtheorem{exmp}[thm]{Example} % same for example numbers
\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}
\newcommand{\bd}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}  % for bolding symbols
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}      % for Real numbers
\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb{Z}}      % for Integers
\newcommand{\col}[1]{\left[\begin{matrix} #1 \end{matrix} \right]}
\newcommand{\comb}[2]{\binom{#1^2 + #2^2}{#1+#2}}
\renewcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{section}{0}
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}
  \setcounter{figure}{0}
  \setcounter{table}{0}
  \renewcommand\thesection{Appendix \Alph{section}}
  \renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{section}\arabic{figure}}
  \renewcommand\thetable{\Alph{section}\arabic{table}}
}
\begin{document}



\addtolength{\topmargin}{-1cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{2cm}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\includegraphics{UPlogo.jpg}
\vspace{.4in}
\begin{center}
{\Large {\bf DEPARTMENT OF MATHEMATICS}} \\
\vspace{.1in}
{\Large {\bf AND }} \\
\vspace{.1in}
{\Large {\bf APPLIED MATHEMATICS}}
\end{center}
\vspace{.4in}

{\large {\bf \begin{center} \begin{tabular}{|c|} 
\hline CHAPTER 2\\ 2017\\ \hline
\end{tabular} \end{center} }}
\vspace{.5in}
\begin{center}
 {\LARGE\bf 
Computation of Regulatory Capital Charge for Counterparty Credit Risk Under Basel III\medskip\par
}
\end{center}
%\end{figure}
\vspace{0.5in}
\begin{center}
{\bf {\large Erasmus Tyapa\\ (27307612)}}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.2in}
\begin{center}
{\bf {\Large DECEMBER 2017}} 
\end{center} 
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}


\section{Basel I: the Basel Capital Accord}
In 1988, the BCBS intervene to set up first accord on banking regulations.
The accord set rules on capital requirements for banks called  the Basel I for measuring capital adequacy against exposures from credit risk \cite{baselI1988}. 
Under Basel I, assets of banks were categorised and grouped into five groups according to their credit risk, carrying risk weights and no ratings \cite{hull2015risk}. 
The capital adequacy measurements resulted in a broad consensus on a weighted approach to the measurement of risk for both on and off-balance-sheet  assets \cite{baselhistory}. 
Basel I, require banks with international presence to hold at least 8\% capital of the their total credit exposure, called Risk-Weighted Assets (RWA), expressed mathematically  as 
\begin{equation} \label{equa1}
    CAR = \frac{C}{RWA_{c}} \geq  8\%
\end{equation}
where:

\begin{conditions}
C  & is capital required to be reserved for regulatory purpose\\
RWA_c & risk-weighted asset for credit risk\\
CAR  & Capital Adequacy Ratio \\
\end{conditions}  
\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I expected the citation to appear as numerical and the list of used references at the end of document. Here are some of the references

```
@Manual{baselI1988,
  author      = {Basel Committee on Banking Supervision},
  title       = {International convergence of capital measurement and capital standards},
  year        = {1988},
  note        = {Accessed: 2017-02-21},
  publisher   = {Bank for International Settlements},
  url         = {http://www.bis.org/publ/bcbs04a.pdf},
  shortauthor = {BCBS},
  sortname    = {BCBS},
}
@Book{hull2015risk,
  author    = {Hull, John C.},
  title     = {Risk Management and Financial Institutions},
  year      = {2015},
  edition   = {4},
  publisher = {John Wiley \& Sons},
  chapter   = {15},
  pages     = {325-349},
}
@Manual{baselhistory,
  author      = {Basel Committee on Banking Supervision},
  title       = {A brief history of the {B}asel {C}ommittee},
  year        = {2014},
  note        = {Accessed: 2017-02-21},
  publisher   = {Bank for International Settlements},
  url         = {http://www.bis.org/bcbs/history.pdf},
  shortauthor = {BCBS},
  sortname    = {BCBS},
}
```

here is my Texmaker image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8ast.png)

Comment: Did you run biber? Can you share the necessary bib entries to compile your code?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: you really, really ought to clean up the preamble. Don't load the same package multiple times, load `hyperref` later and `babel` earlier. Don't use deprecated font commands liks `\bf`. Don't use math mode for multiletter variables such as RWA, this will mess up the kerning

Comment: @samcarter I did run biber, I attached some bib entries. How do I separate RWA from the math mode when is part of equation, or I mean I must use \text{}?

Comment: Thanks for the bib entries. Looks everything fine so far. Can you show the .log and .blg files?

Comment: If you want the RWA upright, then you can use `\text{}`, if it should be italic: `\mathit{RWA}_{c}`

Comment: I tried to run through the file through CMD ON WINDOW 10, this the error I am getting                                                                                                           INFO - This is Biber 2.13
INFO - Logfile is 'Chapter 2.tex.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find 'Chapter 2.tex.bcf'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1

Comment: You need not run `"biber Chapter 2.tex"` but `biber "Chapter 2"`

Comment: @samcarter Thanks very much, it work perfectly well from the CMD but failing to work on Texmaker

Comment: can you show your texmaker preferences/options/<whatever this is called in windows>?

Comment: here is the texmaker image https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8ast.png @samcarter

Comment: That should be ok. How do you compile in texmaker? With quick build? If yes can you please show the quick build configuration?

Comment: can you also specify what "work perfectly well from the CMD but failing to work on Texmaker" means exactly? Do you get any errors in texmaker? What do the .log and .blg files say?

Comment: Maybe unrelated to your problem: better not use the `build subdirectory` option. It makes configurations much more difficult. Actually this might explain the problem you have. Can you try without this option?

Comment: Thanks @samcarter, it was the build subdirectory  problem, uncheck it, and now is all fine. Maybe I should email you, to help clean my preamble? Thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe you could ask a question for your preamble at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tex ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the use of the `build subdirectory` in the texmaker preferences. This makes the configuration much more difficult because each and every individual tool needs to be adjusted to use this.

#### Easy solution:

don't use this option, it only makes things more complicate

#### Advanced solution:

If you really really want to have keep your directory clean and have all the auxiliary files in a separate directory, you can use some of the latex automation tools. For example [ltx2any](https://github.com/reitzig/ltx2any) will automatically compile your document (including all the additional steps to create a bibliography, index etc.) while keeping your folder clean